# Can't pass function as Context Values in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-typescript

This is probably a noob mistake. But I can't declare a function inside createContext object. Here's my Code.

```
    import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { verifyJWTToken } from "../utils/functions";
    
    type authValues = {
      isAuthenticated: boolean;
      user: {};
      toggleAuth: () => void;
    };
    
    export const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<authValues>>({});
    
    interface authContextProps {}
    
    const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<authContextProps> = (props) => {
      const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);
      const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    
      const toggleAuth = () => setIsAuthenticated(!isAuthenticated);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
        if (localData) {
          const res = verifyJWTToken(JSON.parse(localData));
          if ((res as any).err) {
            console.log("Not Authenticated");
          } else if ((res as any).user) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            setUser((res as any).user);
          }
        }
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{ isAuthenticated, toggleAuth: { toggleAuth }, user }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    
    export default AuthContextProvider;
```

The problem here is that I can't send the function toggleAuth as the value of AuthContextProvider.
The vscode error says

```
    Type '{ toggleAuth: () => void; }' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'toggleAuth' does not exist in type '() => void'.ts(2322)
    AuthContext.tsx(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'toggleAuth' which is declared here on type 'Partial<authValues>'
```

The Reactjs error says

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: toggleAuth is not a function
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well you're not passing it a function, you're passing it an object with a function property. It just needs to be `toggleAuth: toggleAuth`.

Comment: oopsss, like I said, that was a noob mistake, thanks btw

Comment: Can you take a look at that useEffect function? It's causing a lot of problems for me

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Like I said, That was a noob mistake. Like @Brian Thompson said I had to pass it as an object, not an object.

Comment: Perhaps a code example would help?